# Failing to install sqlite3 plugin for electron project on windows

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, electron, node-gyp

I am trying to include sqlite3 in an electron project I am getting my hands dirty with. I have never used electron, nor Node before, excuse my ignorance. I understand that to do this on Windows, I need Python installed, I need to download sqlite3, and I need to install it.

As per the NPM sqlite3 page, I am trying to install it using `npm install --build-from-source`

It always fails with

> unpack_sqlite_dep
>     'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.

I have Python 2.7 installed and the path has been added to environment variable PATH. I can verify that if I type 'python' in cmd, I get the same response. BUT, if I type 'py', it works....

So, my question is: how can I make node-gyp use the 'py' command instead of 'python' when trying to unpack sqlite3?

If this is not possible, how can I make 'python' an acceptable command to use?

I am using Windows 10 if this helps. Also, please let me know if I can do this whole procedure in a different way.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved....

Uninstalled Python 2.7.13. Reinstalled, added path to PATH variable again, now command 'python' works just fine...